# why I see / as the top active page in google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

Why I see `/` as the top active page in google analytics?

When I search my keywords in google I will not get refer to our main page but I get shown Subpages.

google analytics
overview
top active page

please help me

[image: google analytics shows / as the most active page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see it because `/` is the root of the site. In URL `https://stackoverflow.com/` the `stackoverflow.com` bit is the the host (may be accompanied by port like `localhost:1234` or `example.com:1234`) and the `/` bit after the host (or after the port) is the path. Now like in Unix `/` path is the root, so it's what you call "main page", not what you call "subpages".

```
https://stackoverflow.com/
        ^ host           ^ path
```

If you are confused by the fact the path is a folder, not a file, here's what can help you: usually servers has certain default routings, meaning that usually for user `example.com` is routed to `example.com/` which is routed to `example.com/index.html` (or `example.com/index.php`). So again, `/` means "main page" if you prefer that term.

PS But if your question is why your main page is the most actively visited, I don't think anyone can help without more information. How do we know? It's just the most actively visited one. Though, your picture shows *active* pages meaning pages that are *currently* opened by somebody, there's 5 users. With such small numbers, fluctuations are high.